# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Converting Characters

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, collation

I'm working with a CSV that contains characters like:

```
” and •
```

I am reading the CSV via OleDb and the provider is Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. when the data is loaded into the OleDbCommand, the characters are converted to the following respectively:

```
â€œ and â€¢
```

I suspected there might be a collation setting in the connection string but I was unable to find anything about this.

I can confirm the following:

1. I can see the original character in the CSV when I open it.
2. If I run a select on the file through OleDb WHERE [field] LIKE '%•%' I get 0 rows but if SELECT WHERE [field] LIKE '%â€œ%' I get rows returned.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I get the data to load using an OleDbConnection and stop it from converting the characters when a select is run?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally! Thanks to @HABJAN I was able to get to the resolution which is as simple as setting the CharacterSet in the Extended Properties of the connection string. For my situation it was UTF-8... commonly used by default in PHPMyAdmin which is where my data was retrieved from.

Resulting working connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;CharacterSet=65001;\""
```

Key is CharacterSet=65001 ([Code Page Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers)) which might have been obvious to some collation-savvy individuals but I've somehow managed to avoid these issues over the years and never come across it in this respect.

I was also able to get HABJAN's solution to work when also following the documentation found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver and setting the CharacterSet to the same as above.

For my situation, this is the better method as it is a simpler/more maintainable solution, but +1 to HABJAN for helping me get there!

Thanks

Comment: as per MSDN i see there are only 2 options to set for CharacterSet as ANSII or OEM. But, I see you mentioned the code explicitely for UTF8. Is this working and any other code like 1252 works as well?                                 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver#selecting-a-character-set

Answer (score 4):

You can create [`schema.ini`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file and play with format and `CharacterSet` properties.

Take a look at this sample: [How to read data from Unicode formatted text file and import to Data Table using .Net](http://techshirly.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-read-data-from-unicode-formatted.html)

And here is another sample that will show you how to read csv file with schema.ini: [Importing CSV file into Database with Schema.ini](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Importing_CSV_Database_Schema.ini.aspx)