# Getting error "String cannot be of zero length" when replacing a French quote character with normal single quote

Tags: c#, string

C# .NET Framework 1.1: I am trying to replace a French quote character with a normal single quote. It is working on most of our development environment (machines) but when moved to the system test environment, getting a `string cannot be of zero length` error.

Here is my code:

```
//replace French Quote with normal single Quote
fileColumnName = "date d’embauche";
fileColumnName = fileColumnName.Replace("’","'");
```

Is it some issue with character encoding at the testing environment?

Update: Forgot to mention: It is a COM+ component; do we have character encoding settings in COM+?

Sorry for not being very clear; here is a large portion of the code: It may be confusing, so to make it clear:

`fileData` is a data table (System.Data.Table) which is populated by an OLEDB connection to the CSV file. Then I get column names which are compared against the names stored in the database (headerData).

```
//#5:  Invalid header row check
foreach(DataRow hrow in headerData.Rows)
{

        columnNameEnglish = hrow["EnglishDisplayValue"].ToString().ToLower();                //get english column definition
        columnNameFrench = hrow["FrenchDisplayValue"].ToString().ToLower();                        //get french column definition
        columnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(hrow["DataBaseValue"]);                                                //get corresponding index
        fileColumnName = fileData.Columns[columnIndex].ColumnName.ToLower();

        //replace french Quote with normal Quote
        fileColumnName = fileColumnName.Replace("’","'");

        //check English
        if(fileColumnName.IndexOf(columnNameEnglish) < 0)
        {        
                //check French
                if(fileColumnName.IndexOf(columnNameFrench) < 0)
                {        
                        //invalid row 
                        errs.Add("81181");
                        break;
                }
        }                                        
}
```

Comment: For some reason the file encoding is wrong on the test system? Perhaps the source file is in an ISO-8859-x format and the test system's default locale does not match the encoding? You should just *always* save as UTF-8 and these problems will never appear.

Comment: thanks Jon, let me check that. Interestingly we have a plain English file also (with no such special char) but still getting this error!

Comment: @Jon, is `UTF-8` to file formats like `UTC` is to dates?

Comment: Have you tried using a different culture for example `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");` ?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: Kind of :-) The C# compiler in particular parses UTF-8 and UTF-16 in the same manner always, single byte encodings are dependent on local settings.

Comment: forgot to mention, it is a COM+ component, not sure if it has to do something with that. Question updated.

Comment: `string.Replace` does not behave differently depending on any variable or setting. All strings in .Net are UTF16 LE. You are not showing us something in your code which effects how `fileColumnName` is instantiated.

Comment: Try using a Unicode literal "\x00B4" in place of the quote. This will get around any source code file encoding issues.

Comment: I am still not convinced with that this is the problem with the 'file encoding', I tried with the same file used for system testing and it worked on my DEV system!

Comment: OK, I found this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794072/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-converting-characters and trying that. will update you all soon..

Comment: Is there a _reason_ WHY you are using .NET _1.1_?

Comment: @Cole Johnson: this application was developed years back and my company didn't want to upgrade yet to the new frame work,  - we are developers more than happy to upgrade though :-)

Comment: @shibin If I recall correctly, .NET is backwards _code_-compatable (but _not_ backwards _library_-compatable). So, you can write code using .NET 1.1, compile against .NET 4.0, then run against .NET 4.5 if you want. But if you compile against .NET 3.0, you're gonna need .NET 3.0 or 3.5 to run. But your .NET 1.1 code should still compile against .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem. I found it sometime back but forgot to update here.

Thanks to @Ben. As per his suggestion I used Unicode literals ('\u2019') and it woked like a charm. I guess it was the CodePage issue of the test server, but this will not affect Unicode literals.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, for some reason, your string at the point you attempt to replace is of 0 length. This indicates that the problem has to do with the contents of the column you retrieve from the DB. As such, I suggest that you check in your code if the string is null or empty before trying to replace.