# Read CSV File having double qutoes using linked server in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, mssql-jdbc

I have first time created Link Server in SQL Server to read a `.csv` file. I was  able to create connection but facing an issue with non-English characters - they not appearing on proper format as they are in `.csv` file showing some random text:

[image]

Original values for following column `FirstName` and  `BusinessEnitityiID` in csv file were as below:

[image]

This is code use to create link server

```
EXEC master.dbo.SP_ADDLINKEDSERVER 
     @server =N'CSV',
     @srvproduct=N'CSVFILES',@provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', 
     @datasrc=N'C:\SSIS\data',
     @provstr=N'Text'
```

Linked server connection in SQL Server looks like this:

[image]

Expected output should be as below

[image]

Comment: Don't trust what you see in the client tool, use `UNICODE` to inspect the value https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/unicode-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 Also, perhaps this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794072/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-converting-characters

Comment: I am selecting following driver Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 /Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 for linkserver connection.

Comment: Ok. Did you try some things in that link?

Comment: I am using mssql management studio to connect linkserver ,unable to define connection string as you mention in you comment. i also check if there is any non printable character which causing issue but no able to find.