# Visual Basic .NET - Replace a Specific Pair of Characters in a 'String'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I'll put more detailed information that may not exactly be relevant below the line.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022, and my project is a 'Windows Form App' using Visual Basic (Form1.vb)

As basic as I can explain this, I have a pair of characters I need to replace in a character set, in this case `00`, with some other character set (lets use `2A`).

The example string I have is `0020004500750072`. The end string I want should be `2A202A452A752A72`

I need to replace the `00` pairs in sets of two. So replacing the first set of 00's is alright, but then I need it to skip the 0 that's paired with the 2, and replace the 00 pair after it.

---

So all of my information is coming from a .dbf file that I assume was made with FoxPro. The version is `03`, or [FoxBase 2.x / dBASE III](http://www.independent-software.com/dbase-dbf-dbt-file-format.html).

I can import that into my VB project as a data table with this code-

```vb
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
{
    .DataSource = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
}
builder.Add("Extended Properties", "dBase III")
Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString}
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & IO.Path.GetFileName(path)
        cn.Open()
        'Dim dt As New DataTable
        GlobalVariables.dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
End Using
DataGridView1.DataSource = GlobalVariables.dt.DefaultView
```

While this works almost perfectly, for some reason one of the columns is formatted with null values between every character - `5400650063006800` or `T.e.c.h.` The data column only displays the first character, terminating with the null value after it.

I can get the program to import the file as a single string of values using this code-

```vb
Dim s As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
Dim encoding As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
Dim B As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(s)
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

For Each singlebyte As Byte In B
    sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", singlebyte)
Next
```

My problem is how to search for those null vales (after the header) and replace them with a different value, shove this into my data table, make the changes I need to make, reconvert back to the null values, and export the file again.
For reference, this is my save script for just saving a straight text box as I need it to be. Not sure how to go about saving my data table after I edit it.

```vb
Dim FILE_NAME as String
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    FILE_NAME = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim a As String = txtALL.Text
    Dim b As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To a.Length - 2 Step 2
        b = b & Chr(CInt("&H" & a.Substring(i, 2)))
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(b)

    Dim objWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
    objWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
    objWriter.Write(b)
    objWriter.Close()
End If
```

---

Having said all that, I don't exactly need to use a data grid to view/edit the information. If someone can give me a script to separate out the information blocks so I can easily edit each 'item' in a text box or something, I can just as easily do that.

The header is 834 characters long, with each record then being 1258 characters, and a final terminating character of `1a`.
So for a total length of 1833742, minus the 834 header, minus the 2 terminator, and divided by 1258 per record gives 1457 records.

Comment: That's not an ASCII encoding but UTF-16. It is not clear what this column contains. Is it a binary value or is it a text column containing a text in UTF-16 encoding or is it an ASCII text containing a hexadecimal value representing a UTF-16 string? It is not clear how the FoxPro or dBase column is declared and what `GlobalVariables.dt.Load` does.

Comment: When I open the file in Notepad++, the column (or what should be a column in the long line of text) in question has values that look like this- `TNULeNULcNULhNUL`. Looking at it with the HEX Editor plugin gives me the this- `5400650063006800`

Comment: As for the .dt.Load, I think that loads the file in a DataGridView friendly format? IDK I'm mostly a copy-paste coder for complex stuff like this.

Comment: The details of this Load method matters. Maybe the tool [dBase Explorer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2203/dBase-Explorer) will help you to understand the table structure.

Comment: That program seems to act the same way, only showing the first character and stopping with the following NUL (ex. the T in T**NUL**e**NUL**c**NUL**h**NUL**)
Everything else loads and appears correctly and as I expect it to.

Comment: And what does the column view show for this column?

Comment: Does [Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Converting Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794072/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-converting-characters) help? (You might need 1200 instead of 65001.)

Comment: Just a little side, Don't know what the source of this data is, but wouldn't it make much more sense to fix the problem there rather than mopping up after the fact?  Or at the very least look how that's handing this data because no doubt that will have the same issue?  Or is it being dBase/Foxpro that source is no longer supported?  And if you do parse the file structure as per your requirements, is that going to break the source?

Comment: **Andrew**: It's possible that something like that might help, but the example you linked to is C#, I'm working in VB and would have no idea how to shuffle it around to work.

**Hursey**: Unfortunately I don't have access to the source data, just the file I'm needing to edit.

Comment: @GriffinManning It's only something that you add into the connection string, like you already have in the `builder.Add` line. [Also, you need to use an @ in front of the username in a comment for that person to be notified. One @ person per comment.]